# How to refresh page after changing array with objects?

Tags: knockout.js

I would like to know how to refresh the page after changing array with objects.

For example: I have a pop-up window with a list of users. I can add a user ( new Object to an array) to that list by the input field.

When I add a new user, that user doesn't appear on the popup without refreshing. Only when I refresh the page and open that popup I can see that user in my list.

How can I do it in knockout so that I don't need to refresh the page?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: knockout is a MVVM binding library. To update the frontend you just need to update the underlying objects. That said your question is very unclear

Comment: Thank you, **Liam**, but after update objects, frontend doesn't update.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Comment: [Knockout documentation: `foreach` binding example with add and remove](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#example-2-live-example-with-addremove). Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/N3JaW/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a user to an observable array by using the Knockout-provided [array functions](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#manipulating-an-observablearray) for observable arrays. Do not manipulate the underlying array by getting it out of the observable array object, because changes made that way are not observed by Knockout.